# To what extent does rust compiler auto match generic constraint?

Tags: rust

Consider the following code for binary tree

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Binary_Tree_Node<T: PartialOrd + Clone> {
    left: Binary_Tree<T>,
    value: T,
    right: Binary_Tree<T>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Binary_Tree<T: PartialOrd + Clone> {
    node: Option<Box<Binary_Tree_Node<T>>> 
}

impl <T: PartialOrd + Clone>Binary_Tree<T> {
    fn new(value_to_insert: T) -> Binary_Tree<T> {
        Binary_Tree{node: 
            Some(
                Box::new(
                    Binary_Tree_Node{
                        left: Binary_Tree{node: None}, 
                        value: value_to_insert, 
                        right: Binary_Tree{node: None}
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    }

    fn map<F, U>(&self, f: F) -> Option<U> 
    where F: FnOnce(&Binary_Tree_Node<T>) -> U {
        self.node.as_ref().map(|node| f(&**node))
        // equivalent 
        //self.node.as_ref().map(|node| f(node))
    }
}
let mut test1 = Binary_Tree::new(10);
println!("{:#?}", test1.map(|node| node.value < 2));
```

This line confuses me

```
self.node.as_ref().map(|node| f(node))
```

as I expect rust to throw compiler error

`self.node` is of type `Option<Box<Binary_Tree_Node<T>>>`

`self.node.as_ref()` is of type `Option<&Box<Binary_Tree_Node<T>>>`

`node` in `self.node.as_ref().map(|node| f(node))` is of type `&Box<Binary_Tree_Node<T>>`

`&Box<Binary_Tree_Node<T>>` is not equivalent to the generic constraint `&Binary_Tree_Node<T>`

The question is why both `self.node.as_ref().map(|node| f(&**node))` and `self.node.as_ref().map(|node| f(node))` work?

Comment: I think in the current form this question is not useful for others.  Could you perhaps provide a [mcve] and remove the unneeded context? And edit the title to reflect the "unexpected" `&Box<T>` -> `&T` conversion (because I can't see how this relates to "generic constraint")?

Answer (score 4):

This is a "Deref coercion", see [nomicon Coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html):

> Coercion is allowed between the following types:
>
> - [...]
> - Deref coercion: Expression `&x` of type `&T` to `&*x` of type `&U` if `T` derefs to `U` (i.e. `T: Deref<Target=U>`)

`Box<T>` implements `Deref<Target=T>`, so `&Box<T>` coerces automatically to `&T` like you'd have written `&*node`.

(I'm not sure what the `&` in "Expression `&x`" part is for, because we don't have a `&` at coercion site and it still works - could be a typo or a bug)

Also works from `&String` to `&str`: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b3d4bc58f26d8453c8fd3f0f2b1ade93&version=stable)

```
fn foo<T>(_v: T) {}

fn main() {
    {
        let v: &Box<i32> = &Box::new(5i32);
        foo::<&i32>(v);
        foo::<&i32>(&*v);
    }

    {
        let v: &String = &String::from("abc");
        foo::<&str>(v);
        foo::<&str>(&*v);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kroltan As far as I can tell only references are coerced with Deref; maybe you're talking about ["The Dot Operator"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dot-operator.html) (also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules/28552082#28552082)?